# How to update the table when same record is inserted using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating POS application, When I select product from auto complete product from database like SONY qty is 1 by default, when again this select product SONY I want below table only update qty not an add new row update qty when same code please guide me.

```
function addProduct() {
        var procode_1 = $('#procode_1').val();

        var product = {
            procode: $('#procode_1').val(),
            prname: $('#proname_1').val(),
            qty: $('#qty_1').val(),
            price: $('#price_1').val(),
            tot_cost: $('#totcost_1').val(),
        };

        addRow(product);

        $("#proname_1").val(' ');
    }
function addRow(product) {
var qty = $('#qty').val();
if ($('#procode_1').val().length == 0) {
        $.alert({

            title: "Error",
            content: "Please Enter Stock Code",
            type: "red",
            autoClose: 'ok|2000'

        });
    } else if (!$('#currentstock_1').val() < qty) {
        $.alert({

            title: "Error",
            content: "Product is not enough!",
            type: "red",
            autoClose: 'ok|2000'

        });
    } else {
        sr++;
        $('#productlist').show();
        var $tableB = $('#productlist tbody');
        var $row = $(
            "<tr style='text-align: center;'>" +


            "<td width='5%' style='display: none;'>" + sr + "</td>" +
            "<td width='15%'>" + product.procode + "</td>" +
            "<td width='20%'>" + product.prname + "</td>" +

            "<td width='20%'  >" + product.qty + "</td>" +

            "<td width='5%'   >" + product.price + "</td>" +

            "<td class='totalLinePrice'>" + product.tot_cost + "</td>" +
            "</tr>"
        );

        $row.data("lineitem", product.sr);
        $row.data("procode", product.procode);
        $row.data("prname", product.prname);
        $row.data("qty", product.qty);

        $row.data("price", product.price);

        $row.data("tot_cost", product.tot_cost);

        $tableB.append($row);

        total += Number(product.tot_cost);

        $('#sub_total').val(total);
        $('#total_invoice').val(total);
    }
}
```

[Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lo2pv.jpg)
[I want this show in image please check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAMVL.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified your code to make everything more readable. Comments should be enough to understand how it works.
I hope it helps you.

```js
$('#add').click(function() {

  var c = $('#code').val();
  var q = $('#qty').val();

  // Important here is the new class='qty'
  var $row = $(
    "<tr style='text-align: center;'>" +
    " <td width='80%' style='border-right:solid 1px black;' >" + c + "</td>" +
    " <td class='qty' width='20%'>" + q + "</td>" +
    "</tr>"
  );
  
  // Check if code exists
  var exists = false;
  $('#productlist tbody tr').each(function() {
    
    // If exists a product with the same productCode...
    if ($(this).data('procode') == c) {
      
      // Flag exists
      exists = true; 
      
      // Update old quantity internal data
      $(this).data('qty', parseInt(q) + parseInt($(this).data('qty'))); 
      
      // Update table with new value
      $('.qty', this).html($(this).data('qty'));
      
    }
    
  });

  // If not, we create a new row
  if (!exists) {
    $row.data("procode", c);
    $row.data("qty", q);
    $('#productlist tbody').append($row);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="display:inline-block; width: 50px">Code:</div> <input id="code" type="text" />
<br/><br/> 

<div style="display:inline-block; width: 50px">Qty:</div> <input id="qty" type="text" />
<br/><br/>

<div style="display:inline-block; width: 50px"></div> <button id="add">Add</button>
<br/><br/><br/>

<table id="productlist" style="width:300px; border:solid 1px black;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th width='80%' style='border-right:solid 1px black;'>Product Code</th>
      <th width='20%'>Qty</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks so mush issue has solved, this code is very helpful.

Comment: i ask one thing more that if table form value have 10 qty one i select item should be updated 11 qty  but in this your code only 1 qty is updating like 1 will update 2 not 11 please resolve this issue thanks

Comment: The code seems to work properly, if I add 1 to an item with `qty = 10` it becomes `11`. `parseInt (...)` converts a `string` into an `integer`. [Here a JSFiddle example (link)](https://jsfiddle.net/StepBaro/a40ztq98/4/) with the same code but with an auto fill timeout.